# How to display text when clicking on a canvas.object (tkinter)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make a GUI with Python 3.6 and tkinter 8.6. At a moment, I want to make a graph, with circles representing the apex. I began to build it with canvas.objects, but now I'm trying to display some text when the user click on circles, and I can't find how to do this. Must I use some tk.Buttons, or is there another option ?

Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import math


def create_graph(n,R):

    master = Tk()
    cv = Canvas(master, width=500, height=500)
    cv.grid()
    cv.create_oval(240, 240, 260, 260, fill = "black")
    for i in range(n):
        a,b = 250+R*math.cos(2*math.pi*i/n),250+R*math.sin(2*math.pi*i/n)
        temp=(a,b)
        cv.create_oval(a-10,b-10,a+10,b+10, fill = "black")
        cv.create_line((250,250),temp)
    cv.mainloop()

create_graph(10,100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need a button to register mouse clicks. The canvas can catch those events itself. You can add something along these lines:

```
def callback(event):
    cv.focus_set()
    print("clicked at {} {}".format(event.x, event.y))

cv.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
cv.pack()
```

Then, you can use the coordinates received to test if you are inside one of your circles or not, and take appropriate action.

BTW, are you sure you should run `cv.mainloop()` and not `master.mainloop()`?

Comment: `cv.mainloop()` worked but it was not intentional, I suppose `master.mainloop()` is better ^^ !